Excel extracting values from multiple tests
Ultimately I am trying to find the average of the top 3 values per test on the latest day for "Person 1". I am able to find the latest day using the Large(If()) formula, and I am able to plug that into a Unique(Filter()) function to find the corresponding "test" numbers for the day. My problem occurs when I try to extract the actual results from the test. My data is:


Person            Date         Test    Rep    Result
Person 1    10/9/2023   1   5   1.06459372
Person 1    10/9/2023   1   4   1.11329722
Person 1    10/9/2023   1   3   0.91809
Person 1    10/9/2023   1   2   0.92332983
Person 1    10/9/2023   1   1   0.81854742
Person 1    10/9/2023   2   5   0.79415372
Person 1    10/9/2023   2   4   0.78722627
Person 1    10/9/2023   2   3   0.77623751
Person 1    10/9/2023   2   2   0.75960889
Person 1    10/9/2023   2   1   0.55552335
Person 1    10/9/2023   3   5   1.25761919
Person 1    10/9/2023   3   4   1.38660111
Person 1    10/9/2023   3   3   1.28825923
Person 1    10/9/2023   3   2   1.11500258
Person 1    10/9/2023   3   1   0.93898195
Person 1    10/9/2023   4   5   1.01453846
Person 1    10/9/2023   4   4   1.06929
Person 1    10/9/2023   4   3   0.93578771
Person 1    10/9/2023   4   2   0.94945872
Person 1    10/9/2023   4   1   0.84496289
Person 1    10/23/2023  1   5   1.58905785
Person 1    10/23/2023  1   4   1.49243315
Person 1    10/23/2023  1   3   1.4587432
Person 1    10/23/2023  1   2   1.58905785
Person 1    10/23/2023  1   1   1.47988413
Person 1    10/23/2023  2   5   0.368215
Person 1    10/23/2023  2   4   1.66144122
Person 1    10/23/2023  2   3   1.3734
Person 1    10/23/2023  2   2   1.75722655
Person 1    10/23/2023  2   1   1.24049032
Person 2    4/29/2024   1   5   1.89406839
Person 2    4/29/2024   1   4   1.90691308
Person 2    4/29/2024   1   3   1.81291382
Person 2    4/29/2024   1   2   1.58922
Person 2    4/29/2024   1   1   1.40970617
Person 2    4/29/2024   2   5   1.70049909
Person 2    4/29/2024   2   4   1.92244355
Person 2    4/29/2024   2   3   1.92599629
Person 2    4/29/2024   2   2   1.63100333
Person 2    4/29/2024   2   1   1.67577882



I am using the formula =FILTER(E:E,UNIQUE(FILTER(E:E,IF((A:A=H3)*(B:B=LARGE(IF(A:A=H3,B:B),1)),C:C)))) where Column E are the test results, and H3 is dropdown for a list of names. This formula gives me a result "#VALUE". I've also tried including a logic where =...,K:K=Unique(Filter())...
For context, I will also be finding integrating a Max to find the max average for the day, if that has any influence on the formula. But my starting point is trying to find the top 3 reps per test on the latest day (10/23/23 for person 1).

Your IFs are missing a value if false

Maybe  filter by person then sort by  date(desc) and result (desc) and take the top three values but too much data to type in and test.

Could you please confirm that dynamic array support and FILTER are available in your installation? They are available in Excel 2021 according to this: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dynamic-array-formulas-and-spilled-array-behavior-205c6b06-03ba-4151-89a1-87a7eb36e531

With AVERAGEIFS, with spill
Here's an option with helper column and AVERAGEIFS; helper column simplifies the formula.

Add a helper column for result ranking
Since it is a dynamic formula, there's no need to fill-down

Rank column:
=LET(
    data, $A$2:$E$5000,
    persons, INDEX(data, , 1),
    dates, INDEX(data, , 2),
    tests, INDEX(data, , 3),
    results, INDEX(data, , 5),
    COUNTIFS(
        persons, persons,
        dates, dates,
        tests, tests,
        results, ">" & results
    ) + 1
)

Results column:
=LET(
    for_persons, H3:H4,
    top_n, 3,
    data, $A$2:$F$5000,
    persons, INDEX(data, , 1),
    dates, INDEX(data, , 2),
    tests, INDEX(data, , 3),
    results, INDEX(data, , 5),
    ranks, INDEX(data, , 6),
    latest_dates, MAXIFS(dates, persons, for_persons),
    AVERAGEIFS(
        results,
        persons, for_persons,
        dates, latest_dates,
        ranks, "<=" & top_n
    )
)



Updated for Excel 2021, without LAMBDA
Assuming availability of FILTER
=LET(
    person, H3,
    latest_date, MAXIFS(
        Table2[Date],
        Table2[Person], person
    ),
    rank_for_result, COUNTIFS(
        Table2[Person], person,
        Table2[Date], Table2[Date],
        Table2[Test], Table2[Test],
        Table2[Result], ">" & Table2[Result]
    ) + 1,
    latest_results, FILTER(
        Table2[Result],
        (rank_for_result <= 3) *
            (Table2[Date] = latest_date)
    ),
    AVERAGE(latest_results)
)

Result:

Formula screenshot:


Corrected 2024-08-07
Grouped by person/date/test per P.b's suggestion

Add a helper column 'rank' for convenience
Latest results grouped for person/date/test
Spill formulas

=LET(
    person_date_test, I2#,
    ranks, G2#,
    top_n, 3,
    AVERAGEIFS(
        Table1[Result],
        Table1[Person], INDEX(person_date_test, , 1),
        Table1[Date], INDEX(person_date_test, , 2),
        Table1[Test], INDEX(person_date_test, , 3),
        ranks, "<=" & top_n
    )
)




Top 3 values per test for max date for person (1)

=REDUCE({"Person","LastestDate","AvgforTop3"},UNIQUE(Table1[Person]),LAMBDA(acc,person,LET(latest_date,MAXIFS(Table1[Date],Table1[Person],person),test_and_results_for_latest_date,FILTER(HSTACK(Table1[Test],Table1[Result]),(Table1[Date]=latest_date)*(Table1[Person]=person)),tests,TAKE(test_and_results_for_latest_date,,1),results,TAKE(test_and_results_for_latest_date,,-1),top_3_per_test,DROP(REDUCE("top_3_per_test",UNIQUE(tests),LAMBDA(acc,test,VSTACK(acc,AVERAGE(TAKE(SORT(FILTER(+results,tests=test),,-1),3))))),1),avg_for_top_3s,(top_3_per_test),

IFNA(VSTACK(acc,HSTACK(person,latest_date,avg_for_top_3s)),""))))

I couldn't fit it in 1 comment, so you need to paste both comments behind eachother. I did not change much on your code. Main change to fix: Moved the AVERAGE from one layer to a prior (around the TAKE(SORT(FILTER(),,-1),3).

=REDUCE({"Person","LastestDate","Test#","AvgforTop3"},UNIQUE(Table1[Person]),LAMBDA(acc,p,LET(latest_date,MAXIFS(Table1[Date],Table1[Person],p),res_latest,FILTER(HSTACK(Table1[Test],Table1[Result]),(Table1[Date]=latest_date)*(Table1[Person]=p)),tests,TAKE(res_latest,,1),results,INDEX(res_latest,,2),top_3,DROP(REDUCE("top_3_per_test",UNIQUE(tests),LAMBDA(acc,test,LET(top3_test_res,TAKE(SORT(FILTER(HSTACK(tests,results),tests=test),2,-1),3),VSTACK(acc,HSTACK(INDEX(top3_test_res,1,1),AVERAGE(INDEX(top3_test_res,,2))))))),1),VSTACK(acc,IFNA(HSTACK(p,latest_date,top_3),HSTACK(p,latest_date))))))

I used shorter names to be able to paste. This version includes test column

I could potentially make it a table if it helps, however my office subscription doesn't have the LAMBDA or MAP function. I am working with Office Professional Plus 2021. A quick search seems to show that function hasn't been pushed out to my version.

Thank you very much P.b ! I'll make those changes. @Cra538, while you check out P.b's solution, I'll put try to put together  table and non-table versions later today.

Yes I do have FILTER in my version. @nkalvi, the version with the FILTER availability worked. Thank you!

@nkalvi The updated still shows the average of top3 per person, but not per test per person. Have a look at the results from my suggested version 5 comments above this one. It includes the test ID (which I think may me an unmentioned requirement, because otherwise you know 2 averages, but have no clue where they belong to.

@P.b, I've added an update to reflect your interpretation of the grouped by, I was a bit ambivalent about it initially. Thanks again for corrections and suggestions. I'll delete the previous comments ;)

=LET(f,FILTER(C2:E41,(A2:A41="Person 1")*(B2:B41=MAXIFS(B2:B41,A2:A41,"Person 1"))),MAP(UNIQUE(TAKE(f,,1)),LAMBDA(m,AVERAGE(LARGE(FILTER(TAKE(f,,-1),TAKE(f,,1)=m),{1;2;3})))))
First a filter is created for the max date for person 1 (f).
Next the unique tests are mapped as m. Then the largest 3 values per test are averaged.
This would work in Excel 2021 as far as I know:
=LET(x,"Person 1",
     f,FILTER(Table1[[Date]:[Result]],(Table1[[Person]:[Person]]=x)*(Table1[[Date]:[Date]]=MAXIFS(Table1[[Date]:[Date]],Table1[[Person]:[Person]],x))),
     u,UNIQUE(INDEX(f,,2)), 
     t,SORT(FILTER(INDEX(f,SEQUENCE(ROWS(f)),{2,4}),INDEX(f,,2)=INDEX(u,ROW(A1),)),2,-1),
IFERROR(INDEX(CHOOSE({1,2},INDEX(t,1,1),AVERAGE(INDEX(t,{1,2,3},2))),,COLUMN(A1)),""))

It is incapable of spilling. but you can drag it down and to the right to show the next test average of 3.
It shows the test name/ID in the first column you paste it in and the average of top 3 values of that test in the column to the right of it, when dragged.

Thank you, I am sure this would work. Unfortunately my office subscription doesn't have the LAMBDA or MAP function. I am working with Office Professional Plus 2021. A quick search seems to show that function hasn't been pushed out to my version.

I'll check later today. But maybe you can use it online: Excel.new ?

@Cra538 check the edit. I worked with table references, let me know it that works for you.
